# Cost allocation map in QGIS

Tags: qgis

[image][image]

I am using QGIS 3.10.
I created raster map indicating the cost of traversing each cell in the north-south and east-west directions which I have used to create a cumulative cost map with the module `r.cost`. It works fine.

However, I try to use the same friccion map with the cost allocation tool and it doesn't work, I get error, although I use the same files than with the cumulative cost tool.

Anyone know if the parameters to use cost allocation map are different? Any suggestions?

Comment: I doubt that the software told you "you get error". Please edit your question so it contains the error message.

Comment: @Erik I edit the error

Comment: Please always provide error messages as text rather than pictures.

Comment: ERROR: Parámetro requerido <output> no definido
ERROR: Mapa ráster <nearestef800cc7b167430d857a12d7cdcce1ea> no encontrado
ERROR: No se encontró el mapa ráster o grupo<nearestef800cc7b167430d857a12d7cdcce1ea> Las siguientes capas no se generaron correctamente.<ul><li>C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp/processing_86bb3bec0cae4ec3906201a94570a694/da315952039648b0b230a8828e0ffacc/nearest.tif</li></ul>Puede comprobar el «Panel de mensajes del registro» en la ventana principal de QGIS para encontrar más información sobre la ejecución del algoritmo.

Comment: ERROR: No se encontró el mapa ráster o grupo <nearestef800cc7b167430d857a12d7cdcce1ea>

Comment: @PolyGeo Basically in 3 of the four error messages it says "raster map or group not found <nearestef800cc7b167430d857a12d7cdcce1ea>

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: What do you mean@PolyGeo? I have already edited the error messages

Comment: Any suggestions @FelixB.